# The sum of the numbers from $100$ to $999$ that do not have the digit $0$ as well as do not have repeated digit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, decimal-expansion

Considering the numbers from $100$ to $999$. Excluding numbers that have the digit $0$, also excluding numbers that have repeated digit. What is the sum of remaining numbers?

That is, we need to find

$123+124+125+\cdots+129+132+134+135+136+\cdots+139+142+143+145+146+147+\cdots+987$

---

Using Microsoft Excel, I found that the answer is $279720$. But I do not know if the calculation can be done in a purely mathematical way (without using any software). I hope you can provide some hints.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: I would always use PARI/GP for such tasks, but nice that Excel does the job as well. No idea how this can be done efficiently (allowing fast calculation by hand) , but I would not be surprised , if someone finds out such an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each digit runs from $1$ to $9$, which sums to $\binom{10}2=45$; for each value there are $8\cdot7=56$ admissible values of the other digits; and the total value of the digits is $111$. So the sum is

$$
45\cdot56\cdot111=279720\;.
$$

Comment: I don't understand "the total value of the digits is $111$."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $45\cdot56$ is the sum of each digit. There are three digits, with values $100$, $10$ and $1$, so we have to multiply by the sum of those values. Sorry if it was unclear; perhaps I was trying too hard to be succinct :-)

Comment: I did not get it before, but got it now. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 4):

Approach that slightly differs from the one provided by Joriki.

If $abc$ denotes such number then so does $a'b'c'$ where $a+a'=b+b'=c+c'=10$.

This indicates that the average of these numbers is: $$\frac12(abc+a'b'c')=555$$

There are $9\times8\times7=504$ numbers that satisfy the conditions.

So the sum of these numbers should be:$$504\times555=279720$$